# 'Rosbag record' with Kinect, facing a disk memory space problem

Tags: kinect, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while I want to record kinect data, using

```
 rosbag record camera/depth_registered/image_raw camera/depth_registered/camera_info camera/rgb/image_raw camera/rgb/camera_info --limit=60 -O kinect
```

The terminal shows that

```
[ERROR] [1383809202.109712616]: Less than 1GB of space free on disk with kinect.bag.active.  Disabling recording.

[ WARN] [1383809202.622705490]: Not logging message because logging disabled.  Most likely cause is a full disk.
```

Why is it? I check my File Systems under System monitor

```
 Device       Directory     type         Total       Free             Available     Used

/dev/sda7     /host        fuseblk     97.4GiB       57.6Gib        57.6GiB       39.8GiB        40%

 /dev/loop0   /               ext3      5.4GiB       482.0MiB       482.0MiB     5.0GiB          92%
```

How could I fix it?

Thanks!

edited:

'rosbag record' directly creats the kinect.bag under 'Home' of Ubuntu, I don't know how to change the location.
The location is also shown in the 'kinect.bag properties' window with 'Location: /root'.
And when I try

```
           rosbag info kinect.bag
```

It shows that

```
             path: kinect.bag 
             version: 2.0 
             size: 4.0 KB
```

Is there any command to change the kinect.bag location?

**To be summarized,
it implies that the disk space is not enough.
how can I change the location of the recorded kinect.bag file into a larger disk location?**

[edit]

I try

```
          rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

and then run rviz and then

```
          rosbag play kinect.bag --clock
```

But cant visualize the data.
And what is '--limit=60' means? And now I just only record only 2 seconds, how to make it longer?
Thank you!

[edit 2]

I tried

```
           rosbag record camera/depth_registered/image camera/depth_registered/camera_info camera/rgb/image_color camera/rgb/camera_info -O /media/8676FBBC76FBAB57/ kinect
```

slightly different from the above one by changing image_raw to image.

And I run rosbag record and it started to record but then gave this

```
           [ WARN] [1383921498.365058698]: rosbag record buffer exceeded.  Dropping oldest queued message.
```

Now I cant see new kinect.bag file in the directory. It is the old one.
I have set false.
Why is it?

[edit 3]

I followed the play back data tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback

Found that ROS time in rviz is the same as the running play back bag time in the terminal.
But there was nothing shown in the rviz.
So either I did not record anything or I used a wrong topic. I checked the recorded file, it is 276.5 MB. So I could use a wrong topic to show it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98611/%27rosbag-record%27-with-kinect,-facing-a-disk-memory-space-problem/) by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the "-O /my_path/my_file" option.

Otherwise, the "-o" is also an interesting option (see [rosbag record](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) ), as it permits to append the timestamp to the filename. So if you record twice the same thing, it won't be overwritten ;-)

[EDIT] (please edit your question instead of putting a comment)
as said in the help given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record)

```
-l NUM, --limit=NUM :
Only record NUM messages on each topic.
```

[EDIT 2] : for the

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

don't forget to put it to false before recording... :-)
And i would recommend you to use both the --clock and --pause option, so it loads and you can replay it when you're ready ^^

[EDIT 3] just remove the --limit=60 and you should be fine :-) Because it means you will only record 60 messages. Which, at a 30 frame/sec rate, will do 2 seconds :-)
So remove this option, and record.

[EDIT 4] you put a space between the directory and filename, instead do -O /media/8676FBBC76FBAB57/my_kinect_file

[EDIT 5] otherwise, try to record each topic in a different file. I personnaly use a launch file, as show below :

```
 <launch>

  <!-- Parameters to change each time-->
    <arg name="depth_registration" default="true" />
    <arg name="path" default="/media/stephane/Data/Imitation_kinect" />



 <!-- Putting the time back to real time-->
    <rosparam>
       /use_sim_time : false
    </rosparam>

 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect1_rgb" args="kinect1/rgb/image_raw kinect1/rgb/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect1_rgb"/> 

<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect2_rgb" args="kinect2/rgb/image_raw kinect2/rgb/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect2_rgb"/> 

<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_tf" args="tf -o $(arg path)/tf"/> 

<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_skeleton" args="/skeleton_1 /skeleton_2 -o $(arg path)/skeletons"/> 


 <!-- Saving the two kinect depth_registered if depth registration is ON -->

<group if="$(arg depth_registration)">

 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect1_depth" args="kinect1/depth_registered/image_raw kinect1/depth_registered/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect1_depth"/> 

 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect2_depth" args="kinect2/depth_registered/image_raw kinect2/depth_registered/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect2_depth"/> 

</group>

 <!-- Saving the two kinect depth if depth registration is OFF -->
<group unless="$(arg depth_registration)">

 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect1_depth" args="kinect1/depth/image_raw kinect1/depth/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect1_depth"/> 

 <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect2_depth" args="kinect2/depth/image_raw kinect2/depth/camera_info -o $(arg path)/kinect2_depth"/> 

</group>


  </launch>
```

Have a good day,

Bests regards

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
Yeah! I tried and it was finally solved But another question aroused. I try 'rosparam set use_sim_time true' and then run rviz and then 'rosbag play kinect.bag --clock'. but cant visualize the data. And what is '--limit=60' means? And now I just only record only 2 seconds, how to make it longer? Thx

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
I just cant visualize the data. rviz shows nothing.
Is it because I did not successfully record data into kinect.bag?
And how to record longer say more than 2 seconds?

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
Plz see [edit 2] in the question. thanks

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
I remove -O directly and it works.
I am sorry that I am a fresh man in the ROS world. I need time to learn your command.
Another thing is that I just want to know how to play back the data in a visualization window or something.
It just play back in the terminal, I cant see anything.
Thanks

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-11-08**:
do rosrun rviz rviz in another terminal. It will open the RVIZ visualisation tool. Then you need to add an image, and select the topic to it. See the tutorials : http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
Plz see [edit 3].
And I should try to get familiar with the concept of the topic of camera and rviz.
I will try to show the image. It is so nice to meet you here. Thanks a lot for your great helping.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Per default, rosbag records to the folder you´re invoking it from and also the "-O kinect" is relative to the current folder. It thus looks like you started it from a folder on a drive that contains less than 1GB of free space. Not knowing the folder from where you invoked your rosbag command line makes it hard to give a more informed answer. Perhaps you can edit your original post with info on that?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-07**:
'rosbag record' directly creats the kinect.bag under 'Home' of Ubuntu,
I don't know how to change the location.
The location is also shown in the 'properties' window with 'Location: /root'
And when I try
rosbag info kinect.bag
It shows that
path:    kinect.bag
version: 2.0
size:    4.0 KB

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-07**:
You can specify the full path when using the -O option. Say you have mounted some usb drive under /media/usb_pen, then you should be able to record to it using "... -O /media/usb_pen/kinect.bag"

**Comment by [Battery](https://answers.ros.org/users/7016/battery/) on 2013-11-08**:
Thank you! I got it!
But now I cant visualize it by play back the data.
And the time duration is only 2 seconds.
You could see my comment below.
Could you give me some more advice?
Thank you!